# Extracted cell forms into a new row with same column name (Reading multiple files)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the value of c2-c5 based on the row b2-b5 and add into rows with the dataframe.

This is a sample data that I am using.

```
..  2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   a   b   c   d   e   f   g
1   a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1  g1
2   a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  f2  g2
3   a3  b3  c3  d3  e3  f3  g3
4   a4  b4  c4  d4  e4  f4  g4
5   a5  b5  c5  d5  e5  f5  g5
```

Code I tried: I have to put the df.loc outside as the values are getting replaced.

```
data=[]
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_excel(file, header=None)
    df['Year'] = file.split('_')[0]
    df['Final'] = df.iat(1,1)
    df['Comments'] = df.iat(2,1)

    data.append(df)
 df1 = df.loc[df[3].isin(['b2','b3','b4','b5']),[3,4]].assign(year=file.split('.')[0]).assign(df['Year]....)
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5    year
.
.
.    .   . abc  def
.    .   .  b2  c2   2019 
.    .   .  b3  c3   2019
            b4  c4   2019
            b5  c5   2019
            b2  c2   2019 
            b3  c3   2019
            b4  c4   2019
            b5  c5   2019
```

Comment: What is format of your file names?

Comment: name_year.xlsd .

Comment: So answer was changed from `.assign(year=2019)` to `.assign(year=file.split('.')[0])`

Comment: But I got other columns too, how do I implement it inside assign function

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Problem is not understand, why need `iat`? Maybe the best add sample data whats hjappen if use it and what is expected output - why use `iat`

Comment: They are cell extracted, i want to combine the df1 with the that column

Answer (score 0):

Idea is filter all values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and add new column `year` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with `append` each filtered DataFrames to list `data` and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
data=[]
for file in files:
    df=pd.read_excel(file, header=None)
    df = df.loc[df[3].isin(['b2','b3','b4','b5']),[3, 4]].assign(year=file.split('.')[0])
    data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Test with sample data:

```
df = df.loc[df[3].isin(['b2','b3','b4','b5']),[3, 4]].assign(year=2019)
print (df)
    3   4  year
2  b2  c2  2019
3  b3  c3  2019
4  b4  c4  2019
5  b5  c5  2019
```

Answer (score 0):

What if I have different years and want to add more different columns?

```
 data=[]
    for file in files:
        df=pd.read_excel(file, header=None)
        df['Year']= filename.split('_')
        df = df.loc[df[3].isin(['b2','b3','b4','b5']),[3, 4]]
        data.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
```